# Computer connecting to malicious IP

Tags: networking, security

#### Setup

- Linux Mint 19, Ubuntu, Ubuntu MATE on one drive
- Windows 10 on the second

#### Problem

- PC connects to 192.241.240.89 on startup
- Also, when opening browser, PC connects to 93.184.220.29

#### Attempts

- Have run multiple anti-rootkit scanners on Windows 10 drive with no positives
- Created a new partition table on the Linux drive
- Added Windows Defender and ufw rules for both IPs
- Sophos and Clam-AV full system scans
- Rkhunter scan, which produced some warning, but im not sure how to act on them further than I have:

  ```
  Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments   [ Warning ]
  Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]
  Suspect files: 0
  Rootkit checks...
  Rootkits checked : 480
  Possible rootkits: 6
  ```

However these haven't worked so far. I am not sure what the next steps would be, I am considering wiping both drives but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: You mentioned 3 OSes (of which only two are on-topic here). From which one the "PC connects to ..."?

Comment: Correction: 4 OSes...

Comment: 192.241.240.89 is the IP address for [tiny.cc](https://tiny.cc/). The other one is a website that just says "CRL Repository" registered to https://www.verizondigitalmedia.com/.

Answer (score 2):

192.241.240.89 appears to be www.tiny.cc, which is a URL shortening service. It's hosted on digitalocean.

93.184.220.29 is a Certificate Revocation List (CRL) from someone. None of these appear malicious.

The browser contacts the CRL to validate the certificate of some site. This is perfectly normal and expected.

There's no reason to believe these to be malicious.